# How to use modified Spark MLlib module as dependency?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, sbt, apache-spark-mllib, sbt-assembly

I want to build a Spark application Jar. My expectation is: when I execute the jar by `./spark-submit`, the application will utilize **my own built mllib(ex:`spark-mllib_2.11-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`)**.

This's my `build.sbt`:

```
name:="SoftmaxMNIST"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/spark-mllib_2.11-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0 
)

// META-INF discarding
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
{
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
}
```

I already dropped my own-built `spark-mllib_2.11-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in to `/My-Project-Path/lib/` directory. But it does not work. **It seems that the application is still using the Spark's default `mllib jar`, in my case it is in `PATH/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/` directory**

PS: The ultimate purpose is that when I run my application on AWS EC2, my application is always using my own-built `mllib` instead of the default one. I may modify my own `mllib` frequently.

Can anyone help me solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how you do `spark-submit`. You have to "convince" (aka modify) `spark-submit` to see the modified jar (not the one in `SPARK_HOME`).

The quickest (not necessarily easiest in the long run) approach would be to include the Spark jars, including the one you've modified, in your uberjar (aka fat jar). You seem to be using sbt-assembly plugin in your sbt project so it's just a matter of `publishLocal` the dependency (or putting in into `lib` directory) and add it to `libraryDependencies` in your project. `assemble` will do the rest.

That will however give you a really huge and fat jar that while in heavy development cycle with lots of compilation, testing and deployment could make the process terribly slow.

The other approach is to use your custom Apache Spark (with the modified library for Spark MLlib included). After you `mvn install` you'll have your custom Spark ready to use. Use `spark-submit` from the custom version and it's supposed to work. You don't have to include the jar in your fat jar and perhaps you won't have to use sbt-assembly plugin whatsoever (just a mere `sbt package` should work).

That approach has the benefit of making your deployable Spark application package smaller and the custom Spark stay separate from development process. Use an internal library repository to publish and depend on.